# Nested Routing Not Working in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

im trying to use nested routing with dynamic values . Normal Routes in App.js are working but the nested route in QouteDetail is not showing anything . console says that  " NO ROUTES MATCHED LOCATION " . Can somebody tell me what's wrong.

CODE :

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route , Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import AllQuotes from './components/AllQuotes';
import NewQuote from './components/NewQuote';
import QuoteDetail from './components/QuoteDetail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<AllQuotes/>} />
        <Route path="/quotes" element={<AllQuotes/>} />
        <Route path="/new-quotes" element={<NewQuote/>} />
        <Route exact path="/quotes/:quoteID" element={<QuoteDetail/> } /> 
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes , useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Comments from './comments/Comments';

function QuoteDetail(props) {
    const params = useParams();
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>QUOTE DETAILS</h1>
            <h2>{params.quoteID}</h2>

            <Routes>
            <Route exact path={`/quotes/${params.quoteID}/comments`}  element= {<Comments/>} />  
            </Routes> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default QuoteDetail;
```

Comment: You don't need "exact" with Router v6 though

Comment: @MoizSheikh it still wouldn't render the nested route in Quote Detail. Can you tell whats wrong

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, fix the invariant warning for the nested route you are trying to match.

```
You rendered descendant `<Routes>` (or called `useRoutes()`) at "/quotes/1234" (under `<Route path="/quotes/:quoteID">`) but the parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

Please change the parent `<Route path="/quotes/:quoteID">` to `<Route path="/quotes/:quoteID/*">`. 
    in Routes (created by QuoteDetail)
    in QuoteDetail (created by App)
    in App
```

When nesting `Routes` components within other `Routes` components, the paths are built relative from the parent `Routes` component.

Given base `Routes` component:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<AllQuotes/>} />
  <Route path="/quotes" element={<AllQuotes/>} />
  <Route path="/new-quotes" element={<NewQuote/>} />
  <Route path="/quotes/:quoteID/*" element={<QuoteDetail/> } /> 
</Routes>
```

Use the path `"/comments"` to build relatively from the parent `"/quotes/:quoteID"` path.

```
function QuoteDetail(props) {
  const params = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>QUOTE DETAILS</h1>
      <h2>{params.quoteID}</h2>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/comments" element={<Comments />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nested-routing-not-working-in-react-router-v6]

### Alternative Solution

Alternatively you can move the nested route up to the main `Routes` component and render them nested there.

App

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<AllQuotes />} />
  <Route path="/new-quotes" element={<NewQuote />} />
  <Route path="/quotes">
    <Route index element={<AllQuotes />} />
    <Route path=":quoteID" element={<QuoteDetail />}>
      <Route path="comments" element={<Comments />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Render an `Outlet` in `QuoteDetail` where you want the nested routes to be rendered out.

```
function QuoteDetail(props) {
  const params = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>QUOTE DETAILS</h1>
      <h2>{params.quoteID}</h2>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nested-routing-not-working-in-react-router-v6 (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

The parent route path has no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.

You should change:

```
<Route path="/quotes/:quoteID" element={<QuoteDetail/> } />
```

to:

```
<Route path="/quotes/:quoteID/*" element={<QuoteDetail/> } />
```

Comment: this approach doesnot render the comments component which is routed inside quote details

Comment: Are you getting only that error? I create and example in codesanbox and it worked adding the `*`

Comment: yes only that thing is causing problem if i add * like you said then instead of comments component same quoteDetails components is rendered

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to create route in another functional component, you can create nested routes in App.js with react router 6:

```
<Routes>
...
  <Route path="/quotes/:quoteID" element={<QuoteDetail/> }>
    <Route path="/quotes/:quoteID/coments" element={<Comments/>} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: this works but i nested it inside other component in case of dynamic routing which i dont think works this way

Comment: You did it wrongly, you need to declare nested routes the way I did it in App.js than if you need to jump to other routes you can use: <Link to='/quotes/${params.quoteID}/comments', or you can use useNavigate of react router v6

Comment: One more thing you can render component inside another component like Comment inside QouteDetails but you cant render route inside another component which has different route